# Div inside draggable Div

Tags: javascript, html, draggable

I made a div draggable with `$("#divID").draggable();` and it works.

Inside this div I have a second div. I'd like to have the inner div not draggable,
so that the user can drag the whole thing using a "frame" around the inner div.
The inner div contains a ScrollBar and other elements that conflict with the "draggable" feature.

Is it possibile?
Thank you.

Edit:
I made a test page: [TEST](http://www.fantamorpho.eu/dev/dragTest.php)

The user should be able to drag everything (including "other elements") only in the upper or lower strip, where the cursor become a cross of arrows. I want the user to be unable to drag where the cursors become a pointer.
Thanks again.

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: check out the `containment` property, which "constrains dragging to within the bounds of the specified element or region": http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

Answer (score 0):

I had a vaguely similar issue when working with accordions, I wanted links in the accordion headers and they conflicted with the accordion behaviour.

I fixed it by attaching an event handler to the inner element, and all it did was call `evt.stopPropagation()` to prevent the parent element(s) from getting the conflicting events.

Answer (score 0):

Try position fixed

```
div#notDraggable{
position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Not working. I want the inner DIV to follow movements of outer DIV, just the user cannot click inside it to move it (see example).